# Graph_Tool - Initialize edge properties more efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, graph-tool

I am using **graph-tool** to calculate some centrality measures.

```
from graph_tool.all import *
graph = Graph(directed=True)
```

Before I do that, I need to initialize the edge properties. I am doing the following:

```
weight = graph.new_edge_property('double')
graph.edge_properties['weight'] = weight
```

Adding the edges (from a dataframe). The dataframe has also a column weight.

```
edges = df[['source', 'target']].values
graph.add_edge_list(edges, hashed=True, eprops=[weight])
```

I want to initialize the edge properties using a more efficient way than this (I want to avoid the loop):

```
weight = df[['weight']].values
for edge  in graph.get_edges():
   graph.edge_properties["weight"][edge] = weight[graph.edge_index[edge]]
```

**Can you please suggest a more efficient way to initialize the edge properties?**
The graph is built from a very large dataframe (30 million rows).

Comment: How many edge properties are you expecting?

Comment: I know this question is old but... does anybody found an answer that wants to share with the community?